# calculate the age from a column in a bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

i would like to calculate the age of users from a column (YOB) which contain only the year of birthday ?
i've tried that but it doesnt work :

WITH X AS (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AS YEAR)
SELECT  X - YOB from dataset.table;

Could you help please ?

Thanks!

Comment: please provide sample of input data and expected result - see how to create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Try [DATE_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff).

If YOB is an integer:

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT 1999 AS YOB UNION ALL
  SELECT 2005 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2019
)
SELECT YOB, DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE(YOB, 1, 1), YEAR) AS age
FROM test_data
```

[image]

If YOB is a string:

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT '1999' AS YOB UNION ALL
  SELECT '2005' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019'
)
SELECT YOB, DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), PARSE_DATE("%Y", YOB), YEAR) AS age
FROM test_data
```

[image]